# Number.isInteger() - doesn't work in pow function

Tags: javascript

i created fuction that do like a pow fuction
and i used in Number.isInteger() for do not accept numbers that no integer,
and the isInteger methods doesn't work. what the problem? thanks...

```js
"use strict";

function pow(x, n) {
  let result = x;
  for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    result *= x;
  }
  return result;
}

let x = prompt("x?", "")
let n = prompt("n?", "")

if (n < 2 || (Number.isInteger(n) === false)) {
  alert(`Power ${n} is not supported, use a positive integer`);
} else {
  alert(pow(x, n));
}
```

Comment: x and n are string. parse into int before processing

Comment: thank you very much but i dont really understand you can to write this at code line?

Comment: just wrap like `let x = parseInt(prompt("x?", ""))` for both x and n

Comment: `parseInt` might not necessarily be what you want as it could shadow problems: `parseInt('2adsas')` would result in `2`.